# Modelling a leaderboard/ranking list in Riak

Tags: solr, ranking, riak, leaderboard

I am currently researching databases for a scalable game backend. Riak looks very nice from an operational point of view. I can easily see how to model user and game data and statistics in Riak.  But I have trouble with leaderboards/ranking lists.

Assuming we have millions of players and the ranking would be based on a single highscore integer, what would be the "best" way to store ranking lists? We would need to get the individual rank of a player and paginated lists of all players, say ranks 1-100 or 14500-14600. The score would be updated frequently and the player's rank should update in real time.

Map/Reduce should work, but I guess it would be a little heavy for real time results. I might be completely off here, as I have not done any benchmarks.

What about Riak Search? I don't know Solr at all, so there might be a way to do it, that I missed completely from reading the docs.

[This blog post](http://drew.kerrigan.io/massive-distributed-sorted-sets/) uses a set of sets approach. Coming from a Basho engineer, it's most likely a good solution. But is it the only feasible way to it in Riak? Can we do something a little more "elegant"?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What a great question. When you say something more "elegant", what do you have in mind? I'll share this on the riak-user list next time we have a Recap!

Comment: Thanks. I put "elegant" in quotes, because I'm not sure what to expect. The linked example just seems to do a lot of legwork for a fairly simple task. At least when compared to something like a Redis sorted set. But I guess that's what you get for scalability and ease of operations.

Comment: Fair point. I've noticed leg work is often a tradeoff to quick queries. Not keeping everything in memory makes for a very different set of assumptions at query time. I'll keep this idea floating around internally - feel free to reach out any time! @mjbrender on Twitter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riak search (Solr) may seem a natural choice for at least some of your use cases. It supports sorting (by highest score) and pagination. However, according to Basho, Riak search should not be used when [deep pagination is needed](http://docs.basho.com/riak/2.1.1/dev/using/application-guide/#Search). It also does not scale well beyond 8-10 nodes. Also from my experience there can be a significant delay between storing a value and its becoming fully indexed in Solr, which probably does not meet your real time requirement. So all in all the solution suggested in the blog post seems right.